# When user scrolls down page, space between nav and dropdown menu due to position: fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

## Problem

I have a dropdown menu that appears when the hamburger icon is clicked. The hamburger icon appears when the browser is less than 1300px in width. But due to `position: fixed` the dropdown menu does not appear to move together with the `nav` as one element when the user scrolls down the page. And as a result, there appears to be a gap between the two elements and you see the text between them.

- My work-around has been on scroll to hide the dropdown navigation if its open. However, I don't know if this is the best method as this may cause issues on mobile. I feel a better approach might be changing the structure of the HTML in some way or by using `position: relative`

### Objective

- When I scroll down the page I want the nav and its dropdown menu to move up together

### CodePen: https://codepen.io/onlyandrewn/pen/JNpdde

### index.html

```
<nav id="top">
    <div class="nav__title">
        <a href="/schools/" class="link--title"><h1>School Guide</h1></a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav__wrapper">
        <div class="nav__list--wrapper">

            <div class="nav__hamburger">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <ul class="test">
                    <a href="/schools/about" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>About</li></a>
                    <a href="/schools/all-schools"><li class="item-schools">Schools</li></a>
                    <ul class="inner-text inner-school">
                        <a href="/schools/search/?school_type=Elementary&county=none&distance=" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Elementary</li></a>
                        <a href="/schools/search/?school_type=Middle&county=none&distance=" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Middle</li></a>
                        <a href="/schools/search/?school_type=High&county=none&distance=" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> High</li></a>
                    </ul>

                    <a href="/schools/all-districts" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>Districts</li></a>
                    <li>MAP Scores</li>
                    <ul class="inner-text">
                        <a href="/schools/school-map-scores/" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> By school</li></a>
                        <a href="/schools/district-map-scores/" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> By district</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav__list">
                <a href="/schools/about/" class="nav__link"><li class="nav__item item--about">About</li></a>
                <li class="nav__item item--schools">Schools
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                    <ul class="nav__dropdown dropdown--schools">
                        <div class="triangle triangle-schools"></div>
                        <a href="/results.html?filter=elementary" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>Elementary</li></a>
                        <a href="/results.html?filter=middle" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>Middle</li></a>
                        <a href="/results.html?filter=high" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>High</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <a href="/schools/all-districts/" class="nav__link"><li class="nav__item item--districts">Districts</li></a>
                <li class="nav__item item--map">MAP Scores
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                    <ul class="nav__dropdown dropdown--districts">
                        <div class="triangle triangle-map"></div>
                        <a href="/schools/school-map-scores/"><li>By school</li></a>
                        <a href="/schools/district-map-scores/"><li>By district</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="nav__social">
            <div class="nav__icons">
                <a href="" class="link--nav link--facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="" class="link--nav link--twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="" class="link--nav link--envelope" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam nemo amet excepturi repudiandae sapiente consectetur itaque fugit omnis placeat et, porro reiciendis voluptas molestiae magnam minima. Blanditiis in libero eligendi?</p>
```

### scripts.js

```
  if ($(window).width() < 1300) {
    $(".fa-bars").on("click", function(){
      $(".test").slideToggle();

      if ($(".test").hasClass("is-open")) {
        $(".test").removeClass("is-open");
      } else {
        $(".test").addClass("is-open");
      }
    });
  }

  $(window).on("resize", function(){
    if ($(".test").hasClass("is-open")) {
      $(".test").removeClass("is-open");
      $(".test").hide();
    }

    $(".fa-bars").unbind("click");
    if ($(window).width() < 1300) {
      $(".fa-bars").on("click", function(){
        $(".test").slideToggle();
      });
    }
  });

  $(window).on("scroll", function(){
    if ($(".test").hasClass("is-open")) {
      $(".test").removeClass("is-open");
      $(".test").hide();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I moved the unordered list with the class of `test` to outside of the `nav`
- I removed the `position: fixed` on the dropdown menu

### index.html

```
<nav id="top">
    <div class="nav__title">
        <a href="/schools/" class="link--title"><h1>School Guide</h1></a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav__wrapper">
        <div class="nav__list--wrapper">

            <div class="nav__hamburger">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav__list">
                <a href="/schools/about/" class="nav__link"><li class="nav__item item--about">About</li></a>
                <li class="nav__item item--schools">Schools
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                    <ul class="nav__dropdown dropdown--schools">
                        <div class="triangle triangle-schools"></div>
                        <a href="/results.html?filter=elementary" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>Elementary</li></a>
                        <a href="/results.html?filter=middle" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>Middle</li></a>
                        <a href="/results.html?filter=high" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>High</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <a href="/schools/all-districts/" class="nav__link"><li class="nav__item item--districts">Districts</li></a>
                <li class="nav__item item--map">MAP Scores
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                    <ul class="nav__dropdown dropdown--districts">
                        <div class="triangle triangle-map"></div>
                        <a href="/schools/school-map-scores/"><li>By school</li></a>
                        <a href="/schools/district-map-scores/"><li>By district</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="nav__social">
            <div class="nav__icons">
                <a href="" class="link--nav link--facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="" class="link--nav link--twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a href="" class="link--nav link--envelope" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<ul class="test">
    <a href="/schools/about" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>About</li></a>
    <a href="/schools/all-schools"><li class="item-schools">Schools</li></a>
    <ul class="inner-text inner-school">
        <a href="/schools/search/?school_type=Elementary&county=none&distance=" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Elementary</li></a>
        <a href="/schools/search/?school_type=Middle&county=none&distance=" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Middle</li></a>
        <a href="/schools/search/?school_type=High&county=none&distance=" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> High</li></a>
    </ul>

    <a href="/schools/all-districts" class="dropdown--list-item"><li>Districts</li></a>
    <li>MAP Scores</li>
    <ul class="inner-text">
        <a href="/schools/school-map-scores/" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> By school</li></a>
        <a href="/schools/district-map-scores/" class="dropdown--list-item"><li><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> By district</li></a>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

### style.css

```
.test {
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background: #c62828;
    z-index: 99;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #f4c6c6;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I might be missing something but base on codepen adding

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

to **nav** is really all you need. So adding that on the media query also should solve your need

Comment: In this case, however, I don't want the nav to be fixed. I want the user to be able to scroll past the navigation. The dropdown's current `position:fixed` needs to be changed.

Comment: right but why cant you just add it in the media query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to prevent the menu from scrolling with the page, or get the navbar to remain fixed to the top, but both can be accomplished by using `position`.

To attach the navbar to the top of the page, use `position: fixed` and add some padding to the top of your main content area (enough to account for the height of the navbar).

To keep the mobile menu from scrolling with the page, change its position to relative or static, see what works from those.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, whenever on the smaller screens you need to be able to scroll to see the content. Nav is going up so does the navigation from the hamburger.

just change your class test from position fixed to absolute.

Answer (score 0):

**The fix:**

Change

```
    position: fixed
```

to

```
    position: absolute
```

**Why:**

Both will take the element out of flow, which will have the desired effect of having a size and placement relative to its nearest positioned ancestor rather than it's immediate non-positioned container. While absolute does just that, fixed will also keep the element in the exact same spot on the window, as if it was taped to your computer screen.  This is why it was getting stuck.